# How to connect with MySQL Docker image from host?

Tags: mysql, docker

I am Running a MySQL Docker image and creating database and table. The container is lauched with the command:

```sh
docker run --network host -p 3306:3306 --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql/mysql-server
```

Spark is running on my host machine, So i want to write data from Spark into the database running in the container.

But the connection does not succeed and I am getting an Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without any reproducable code, it's nearly impossible to help

Comment: @KishorPatil: I transformed your comments into a question edit for you just to show you the way ;) There is still not enough information to help you out though. You should show your Spark configuration for DB as well as debugging the connection manually from your host and verify that mysql is running correctly inside your container.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this 2 solutions:

1. Check if your connection URL is not wrong in your java file.
2. Check if your container accept connections that is not localhost of the container:

   Go to your cmd and enter in the container:

   - `docker exec -it containerID /bin/bash`
   - install vim inside container `apt install vim`
   - `vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
   - comment `bind-adress` or make it listen to 0.0.0.0
   - exit from container
   - restart

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

As Schwarz54 mentioned in his answer, it could be host issue.

I usually pass it at the time of initialising the container using the `MYSQL_HOST` parameter.

```
docker run --name mysql_5.7 -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root1234 -e MYSQL_HOST=localhost mysql:5.7
```

I think you don't have to map the ports if you are running it on the host network.

```
docker run --name mysql_5.7 -d --network host -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root1234 -e MYSQL_HOST=localhost mysql:5.7
```

You can mount a local directory to the local container if you want the data to be persisted across container restarts using `-v` flag:

```
mkdir -p /Users/projects/data/mysql5.7
```

And mount this directory in the container at `/var/lib/mysql`

```
docker run --name mysql_5.7 -d --rm -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root1234 -e MYSQL_HOST=localhost -v /Users/projects/data/mysql5.7:/var/lib/mysql mysql:5.7
```